# Cookie Detection , Redirect if Non javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

Tying to write a JavaScript code that will detect if a user has cookies disabled in their browser. If they do, they will be redirected to another page. If they have their cookies enabled it just goes straight through as usual.

i have a code that already works but it still hits the page for a split second before redirection. Is there anyway to make it instant.An example of fast detection is here ( try it with cookies disabled) http://optusnet.com.au
You will see it is instant and doesn't load the page request first.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
/* function to create cookie @param name of the cookie @param value of the cookie @param validity of the cookie */
 function createCookie(name, value, days) 
 { 
    var expires; 
    if (days) 
    { 
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
            expires = "; 
            expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } 
    else 
        expires = ""; 
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"; 
    }

    function readCookie(name) 
    { 
        var nameEQ = name + "="; 
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); 
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
                c = c.substring(1, c.length); 
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length); 
        }
        return null;
    } 

    function eraseCookie(name)
    {
        createCookie(name, "", -1); 
    }

    /* This function will create a new cookie and reading the same cookie. */
    function areCookiesEnabled() 
    {
        var r = false; 
        createCookie("testing", "Hello", 1); 
        //creating new cookie 
        if (readCookie("testing") != null)
        {
            //reading previously created 
            cookie r = true; 
            eraseCookie("testing");
        }
        return r; //true if cookie enabled.
    } 
    </script> 
    <script> 
        if(!areCookiesEnabled()) 
        { 
            //redirect to page
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to reduce the size of your code using Moderizr's updated cookie detect: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/cookies.js

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to make it "instant" with client-side code (i.e. JavaScript) because the page has to be loaded for this code to run. You can achieve this with server-side code, however (like the page you link to does). Here's what you'd have to do, in whatever your server-side language is:

- On the load of your first page, set a cookie and immediately send a redirect instruction to your main page.
- On your main page load, check for the cookie. If no cookie exists, cookies are disabled, so redirect to a third (error) page.
- If the cookie exists, allow the page to load normally.

Alternatively, you can try making it *faster* by reducing the number of HTTP requests required for your "checking" page (i.e. don't include any styles, etc. on the first page and then redirect to a "proper" page if the test passes) and using more efficient detection methods as per Joe's comment; however, you won't be able to implement an immediate redirect with client-side code.

Comment: So the mentioned page uses server side script to do that ?

Comment: @Burfi Yes - that's the only way to perform a redirect without the page loading at all. If you open developer tools or similar before you access the link, you'll see that the immediate response from the server is a 301 redirect.